# Can't load chrome browser with Selenium C# .Net 6/7 MAUI on M2 Mac OS

Tags: c#, .net, macos, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to load a chrome browser and navigate to a page but it just doesn't work with c#, visual studio preview, and .net 6/7, MAUI, Mac M2 I always get this error below.

```
2023-03-07 23:31:56.695 ChromeTestAgain[15349:11436932] System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on this platform.
   at System.Net.Http.NSUrlSessionHandler.set_Proxy(IWebProxy value)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.InvokeNativeHandlerMethod(String name, Object[] parameters)
2023-03-07 23:31:56.695 ChromeTestAgain[15349:11436932]    at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.SetProxy(IWebProxy value)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.set_Proxy(IWebProxy value)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateHttpClient()
2023-03-07 23:31:56.695 ChromeTestAgain[15349:11436932]    at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
2023-03-07 23:31:56.695 ChromeTestAgain[15349:11436932]    at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor executor, ICapabilities capabilities)
2023-03-07 23:31:56.696 ChromeTestAgain[15349:11436932]    at OpenQA.Selenium.Chromium.ChromiumDriver..ctor(ChromiumDriverService service, ChromiumOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeDriverService service, ChromeOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeDriverService service, ChromeOptions options)
2023-03-07 23:31:56.696 ChromeTestAgain[15349:11436932]    at ChromeTestAgain.MainPage.OnCounterClicked(Object sender, EventArgs e) in /Users/grant/Projects/ChromeTestAgain/ChromeTestAgain/MainPage.xaml.cs:line 28
```

To get this error I made a .Net MAUI sample project, I then replaced the sample button click event with this (the sample app it generates with the robot image).

```
IWebDriver driver;
string directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.AppContext.BaseDirectory);
directory = directory + "/Resources";
var chromeDriverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(directory);
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.PageLoadStrategy = PageLoadStrategy.Normal;
driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverService, chromeOptions);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com/");
```

To get the error I need to put the code in a try catch and print the Exception, if I don't do the try catch it just does nothing. The chrome driver does start successfully because in the log I can see this message but the error happens at the same time.

```
Starting ChromeDriver 111.0.5563.19 (378a38865270d286695aeb86f190564911ef7bc2-refs/branch-heads/5563@{#251}) on port 56480
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
```

The error happens as soon as I hit `driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverService, chromeOptions);` The navigate command does nothing, and no browser ever opens. The same `chromedriver` works fine with `Selenium` and `Python`. The problem only exists when trying to use `c#` and `.net`. I have the correct ARM `chromedriver` and the correct driver for my version of chrome. All works with python tests.

Comment: `ChromeTestAgain[15349:11436932]    at ChromeTestAgain.MainPage.OnCounterClicked(Object sender, EventArgs e) in /Users/grant/Projects/ChromeTestAgain/ChromeTestAgain/MainPage.xaml.cs:line 28` post 30 lines of this file. Seems like the problem is at line 28

Comment: Line 28 is driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverService, chromeOptions);